# How can I install a new version of TensorFlow in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Any time I start my lesson with a Coursera Jypiter notebook  in Google Colaboratory, it requires to install the latest TensorFlow version, like

```
!pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview
```

Because the installed version is **1.15.0**

Is there any way to install it **for good** for all my notebooks to be run in Google Colaboratory?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `%tensorflow_version 2.x` to your notebook prior to `import tensorflow`.

Details:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb